# New to ROR, question on Console and accessing data on tables with multiple where clauses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

new to rails and having trouble solving an issue. Any help would be appreciated. Trying to figure out how to get the following data.

I have the following tables

users table (all users and the company they work for):
id
username
company_id

Client table (list of clients and they company they are a client of):
id
company_id

Mapping_user_to_client table (table with which users work on which client):
id
user_id
client_id

I am able to create a list at the user level that shows the clients that the user works on. Where i am having trouble is am trying to create a list of the clients of the company that the user works at but that isn't current assigned to the user.

i've been trying to build the query is rails console, something like: Client.where(agency_id: 1), MappingUserToClient.where.not(user_id: 2) based on what i've been seeing in other examples. But this isn't working. Im sure im doing something completely wrong.  Would appreciate any help or pointing me in the right direction.

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you have an association to `MappingUserToClient` in your `Client` model. i.e.

```rb
class Client < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :mapping_user_to_clients
end
```

Then you can run the following and it will return you all the clients of `agency_id` 1 and those that are not assigned to `user_id` 2

```rb
Client.joins(:mapping_user_to_clients)
  .where(agent_id: 1)
  .where.not('mapping_user_to_clients.user_id': 2)
```

Comment: Hi Kulking, thank you for taking the time to respond to my question. I did have the association on the Client model.    I ran the code you posted. and got back zero results. There is one result that should have returned. I have 4 test clients in the db... three of the clients are assigned to agency (ID:1) and, of those three clients, two of them are assigned to user (id:2). Running the code should have returned the third company.

Comment: Here is what console returned: Client.joins(:mapping_user_to_clients).where(agency_id: 1).where.not('mapping_user_to_clients.user_id': 2)                                                                                                                                                                                            
  Client Load (0.3ms)

Comment: SELECT "clients".* FROM "clients" INNER JOIN "mapping_user_to_clients" ON "mapping_user_to_clients"."client_id" = "clients"."id" WHERE "clients"."agency_id" = ? AND "mapping_user_to_clients"."user_id" != ? /* loading for inspect */ LIMIT ?  [["agency_id", 1], ["user_id", 2], ["LIMIT", 11]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>

Comment: Sorry for the delay but can you post the data from your tables in your question? Please make sure to include `NULL` values as well.